# Как увеличить размер поля ввода?

Tags: html, css

Нужно увеличить размер инпута для того, чтобы его могли свободно заполнять слабовидящие люди. Шрифт в импуте тоже желательно увеличить. Как это сделать на html, может быть, при помощи CSS? Буду благодарен любым подсказкам.

Comment: А какой именно type у input?

Comment: text, comment

Answer (score 3):

css пропиши в файле стили для своего инпута.

```
.class_bla_bla{
 font-size:30px;
  font-weight:bold;
color:#000000;
}
```

ну а тут делай как хочешь. увеличивай шрифт, другой цвет и прочее прочее прочее.

Можно экспериментировать

Answer (score 3):

Форматирование на HTML это старый век надо все делать через CSS

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="" />

<style>
input.text {
    width:  200px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
</style>
```

на класс text вешаем стиль input.text думаю все понятно а параметры хоть какие можно поставить в атрибутах css

Comment: Если используешь height для input объязательно используй padding в IE или Firefox будет глюк текст будет находится не по центру!